# Direct call Python's coroutine from coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

I am creating a class with simple and complex API. Every method which is part of this API should be coroutine. Let's say it looks like this:

```
class MyClass:
    async def complex(self, **kwargs):
        x = compute(kwargs)
        return await asyncio.sleep(x)

    async def simple1(self, param):
        return await self.complex(a=param, b=None)

    async def simple2(self, param):
        return await self.complex(a=None, b=param)
```

From outside this class I still want to call method like coroutines e.g.

```
x = MyClass()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(x.simple1(42))
```

Now I would like to remove the `await` from `simple1` and `simple2` calls because I want to prevent jumps into event loop and back (it feels like wasting time just for the simple call).

Is there any way how to accomplish this? Of course, any solution shouldn't exceed overhead of `await` approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return the co-routine that calling `self.complex()` produces *directly*:

```
class MyClass:
    async def complex(self, **kwargs):
        x = compute(kwargs)
        return await asyncio.sleep(x)

    def simple1(self, param):
        return self.complex(a=param, b=None)

    def simple2(self, param):
        return self.complex(a=None, b=param)
```

This passes the `complex()` co-routine directly to the caller.

After all, all that `MyClass().complex()` does is produce a coroutine object for deferred execution. That same object can be passed around through other synchronous calls, calling `MyClass().simple1('foo')` now happens to create a different coroutine object that directly executes the `complex()` method body rather than produce a wrapper that then defers to the same.

However, the addition of the `async` and `await` keywords make it *clear to the reader of your code* that the methods produce co-routines. The overhead is minimal, consider retaining them.

Comment: This solution effectively hiding that `simple*` is coroutine and another programmer can think it's "blocking" call but it isnt't.

Comment: @Qeek: it **is** a blocking call. It won't return until the `complex()` work is complete.

Comment: maybe I get something wrong about await. When I call coroutine with await does it mean that event loop always process immediately my coroutine even if in the event loop is something waiting for processing (e.g. packet arrived just before i called `await coro()`)?

Comment: @Qeek: Calling a co-routine *function* (one with `async` in the defition name), produces a co-routine *object*. That object is then polled by the event loop to advance it. This is all **exactly the same** as a generator function; such a function produces a generator *object*, which you can then iterate over.

Comment: @Qeek: the event loop intelligently will execute the next available non-blocked coroutine. Your `simple*()` coroutines can be started immediately, but they delegate to `complex()`, so it depends on what that coroutine does wether or not it can be executed.

Comment: @Qeek: so if `complex()` is waiting for I/O, then yes, the event loop will switch to other coroutines added to the loop that are not waiting for anything. The idea being that a well-coded I/O awaitable provides information to the event loop to help determine when it'll be ready to do more work again.

Comment: @Qeek: at any rate, as posted now, `simple1()` and `simple2()` are not blocking now; they just return the co-routine object that `complex()` produces, immediately.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.